# why this insert statement cannot insert values in it's second iteration?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this reasonably sized `stored procedure` that accepts 3 collections two `UDTT` collection and one `CSV` collection.

I have passed the following values to test `stored procedure`. However the problems occurred in one small master table called  `EmpDesignations` with 5 columns. There is a loop I used in the `store procedure` to insert values to `EmpDesignations`. The loop is required because the values are extracted from the `CSV string`. As expected it does iterate 2 times with two sets of values. The first iteration the data was inserted successfully but in the second iteration data was not inserted. I have checked weather the data is empty but those variables `@tmpEmpID` and `@tmp` contain data. So cannot figure out the problem

The `EmpDesignations` table definition is

```
EmpID PK, FK not null
DesigID PK, FK not null
IsValid int not null
UpdtDT datetime not null containts to getDate()
AuthID int not null  EmpID
```

here is the snapshot of the table columns and types

[image]

In the first iteration the passing values to the insert statement is shown in the **watch window**
[image]

As you can see, `@@rowcount` is **1** so worked in the first round!
[image]

In the following watch shows the passing values to the insert statement, this is in the second iteration: 
[image]

But the `@@rowcount` is not `1` therefore the control `rollbacks` all insertions
[image]

Here is a video link of the [debugging of the insert statement](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1nqhv0_error-at-insert-statement_tech)

here is the video of [THE SECOND INSERT statement debugging](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1nqkjb_the-second-insert-statement_tech)

Table definition is correct, the number of values passed matches the number of input columns, and the variables are filled with values in both iterations, so what could be the problem???

here is the script that was generated by SQL server for the table EmpDesignations

```
    USE [SMSV100]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[EmpDesignations]    Script Date: 04/12/2014 08:50:23 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmpDesignations](
    [EmpID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DesigID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsValid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UpdtDT] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [AuthID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EmpDesignations] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EmpID] ASC,
    [DesigID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmpDesignations]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_EmpDesignations_Designations] FOREIGN KEY([DesigID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Designations] ([DesigID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmpDesignations] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_EmpDesignations_Designations]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmpDesignations]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_EmpDesignations_Employees] FOREIGN KEY([EmpID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Employees] ([EmpID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmpDesignations] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_EmpDesignations_Employees]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmpDesignations] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_EmpDesignations_UpdtDT]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [UpdtDT]
GO
```

thanks

Comment: how do you know that @@ROWCOUNT is not 1 in the second iteration? did you save the state of that variable in the second iteration and print it out (can't see that in your code above).

Comment: when the sql executes the 'select' statement right above the 'insert' @@rowcount contains the value 1, but right after executing 'insert' it becomes 0 which means insertion failed right?

Comment: I would create two insert statements manually with those values to see if that sheds light on what is happening.

Comment: @phil, i'l do that I let you know : )

Comment: @Phil, I've added a duplicate insert statement of the insert statement to EmpDesignation, when the first insert statement was executed @@rowcount had 1 and after the executing the duplicate insert statement @@rowcount had 0, thus failed in the first iteration this time

Comment: @phil, even when I pass 5 for desigID same happens, but when I pass 5 to desigID (so now the second insert statement is not an identical duplicate of the first) error hapnens in the second iteration, where execution of the first insert statement @@rowcount had 0 and execution of the second insert statement @@rowcount had 0 therefore in this time at both insert statement execution in the second iteration caused the error

Comment: Is the insert failing because you maybe are trying to insert rows with the same key values?

Comment: @I.K- I thought that too so I have passed a different desigID (=5) please view my videos I have added to my post

Comment: Isn't EmpID the key for that table, you seem to pass in the same value all the time. Can you post the schema for that table please?

Comment: I'm wondering if you have the IGNORE_DUP_KEY setting on...

Comment: @everyone, I had added the script that was generated by SQL for EmpDesignations table

Comment: Is what you have posted in the schema the same as what's in the database server at the moment?

Comment: Are you sure you are not violating any of the constraints? Have you checked that?

Comment: @I.K yes, and tables do not have data because at second iteration they all rolled back

Comment: Try removing the ALTER TABLE statements, and recreate your table. Run your query again and see if you get the same problem. Other than that, I'm not sure what the issue could be. I'm wondering if you are violating the constraints in your database model.

Comment: @I.K, okay i'll check it out and let you know : )

Comment: I notice you've got a foreign key constraint on that table. Sure you're  second insert isn't tripping a violation of that constraint? Either that, or something is sneaking a change to @@ROWCOUNT when you're not expecting it.

Comment: @I.K, did remove alter statement and recreated the EmpDesignations. without the Alter statement, SQL cannot bind GetDate() function to UpdtDT, so I had manually insert Getdate() to the column. GUESS WHAT? it worked. so the problem was UpdtDT and the bound GetDate() so does this mean, I cannot bind GetDate() to UpdtDt (which is a datetime column) ?

Comment: @david, once I recreated the problem (aka without those alter statement that add those FK relationships) worked, is it FK or is it GetDate()

Comment: @david, let me check Fk causes the issue!

Comment: @all- when I add the FK relationships it failed again in the second round. but the master tables Employees and Designations had no insertion problems @@rowcount on those table worked just fine, matter of fact, the insertion only occurred in the Employees as it should be and should not to Designations. Basically it should enter values into two tables, master table Employees and Composite table EmpDesignations. Data gets inserted to Master table Employees successfully but not the composite table EmpDesignations, Could any one here explain any possible issues that could cause this? : )

Comment: one crazy question for this, my system windows 8 basic crashed the laptop shut off while I was debugging SQL and running Visual studio 2012, could this cause these kind of things? im really happy reinstall SQL server and VS2012